# How do I edit my repository after uploading it to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, edit

I want to know how to edit my repository after uploading it to GitHub. What is the process to edit my repository?

For editing, should I edit my code on GitHub or on my PC?

Comment: Sounds like basic git-knowledge to me: https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Voted to re-open.  The linked duplicate isn't an exact duplicate and it doesn't even answer the question.  It barely mentions Github and doesn't explain how to edit your repository there.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally edit the files on your PC, commit them to git locally, and then push the changes to Github.  That allows you to use your local machine's development environment, the text editor or IDE of your choice, and to test your changes before making them available to others.

Github does have editing tools available on its website, so it also possible to edit there.  However, I would only recommend doing that for small changes that don't require compiling or testing.